# derbyにC言語もしくはC++から接続するには？

Tags: c++, c, jdbc

Apache DerbyにC言語もしくはC++から接続して、扱いたいのですが。
できれば、緩めのライセンスで利用できるものを探しています。
何か良い方法はないものでしょうか…。

Comment: 自分で試したわけではないですが、DerbyはODBCを実装しているらしいので、C/C++で実装されたODBCがあれば使えそうですね。  http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/ とか、その方面/キーワードから探してみたらどうでしょうか。

Comment: odbcを実装しているという情報は、どこかに明記されてますでしょうか？
教えて頂いたlibodbc++は、商用有料みたいですね :|

Comment: libodbc++はＬＧＰＬなので商用利用は有料ではありません。

Comment: すみません。ホントですね…彷徨ってる時に勘違いしたようです。